# MVC ASP.NET Best way to get 52 textbox key/values from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm hoping that it isn't to pass each as a parameter to the controller post method..

Have a grid of 52 text boxes representing weeks in a year, each will be containing a decimal value, need ALL of these passed back to the controller for mass updating of the database..

edit: Adding more details.

So my action Index(); returns a view with a list of 52 objects in it.

so

return View(dates);

inside the view I do a foreach for all the objects of that type in the model, and put their values into textboxes, I then want to change them and hit submit.

**is there any way to get the updated list into my POST controller without having to give it 52 parameters with the id's of the textboxes?**

Thanks a lot in advance!

edit: Maybe there is a way I can post the forum to the controller and iterate through the textbox controls and get out id/value, any idea how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggestion using a Model Binder:

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx

http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC__Part_2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question. It should provide you with a better answer than using the FormCollection.

[Complex model binding to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231878/complex-model-binding-to-a-list)

Answer (score -2):

Hey, I got the solution I wanted after a bit of messing about. I just passed in the parameter "FormCollection myForm" and after a bit of exploring within that object I found my 52 values! Thanks for the help.

edit: I deleted this due to peer pressure probably over a year ago... but looking back on it I don't see what the problem was, aside from answering my own question..