# How ASP.NET MVC: How can I bind a property of type List<T>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Let's say I've the bellow model

```
public class UserInformation
{
  public List<UserInRole> RolesForUser { get; set; }      
  //Other properties omitted...
}

public class UserInRole
{
  public string RoleName { get; set; }
  public bool InRole { get; set; }
}
```

On my page I have something like

```
<%using(Html.BeginForm()){%>
  .../...
  <%for(int i =0; i<Model.InRoles.Cout; i++%>
  <p><%: Html.CheckBox(Model.Roles[i].RoleName, Model.Roles[i].InRole)%></p>
<%}%>
```

The idea is to be able to check/uncheck the checkbox so that when the form is posted to the action, the action acts appropriately by adding/removing the user from each role.

The problem is when form is posted to the action method, the Roles property (which is a list UserInRole object) doesn't reflect the change made by the user. ModelBinder works properly on the all other properties but **'Roles property'**

I wonder how I can do that. I suspect that the name/id given to the checkbox is not appropriate. But, I'm just stack. Maybe I should do it differently.

Thanks for helping

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex model binding to a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231878/complex-model-binding-to-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see Phil Haack's post on [model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx).
Essentially what you need to is simply submit a bunch of form fields each having the same name.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<UserInformation>" %>

<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>

  <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.RolesForUser[i].RoleName) %>
  <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.RolesForUser[i].InRole) %>

<% } %>
```

Comment: Well, that's rather easier than I've thought. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, check to see my question. Now that I'm checking your answer, I see that you make the page inherit from IList<UserInRole>. But the model is UserInformation which contains List<UserInRole>. because, I've tried what you suggested, but I still gets null values.

Comment: Try using m => m.RolesForUser[i]

Comment: As I said, your sample doesn't take into account the fact that the page inherits, not from List<UserInRole>, but from UserInformation that contains List<UserInRole>. So, I've to do m => m.RolesForUser[i].RoleName and m => m.RolesForUser[i].InRole. And it worked. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how your submitting your form data. For model binding to work it needs the key name with its associated value. The below code based on your code should bind correctly:

```
<%using(Html.BeginForm()){%>
  .../...
  <%for(int i =0; i<Model.RolesForUser.Count; i++%>
  <p>
     <%: Html.Hidden("UserInformation.RolesForUser[" + i + "].RoleName", Model.RolesForUser[i].RoleName) %>
     <%: Html.CheckBox("UserInformation.RolesForUser[" + i + "].InRole", Model.RolesForUser[i].InRole) %>
     <%: Model.RolesForUser[i].RoleName %>
  </p>
<%}%>
```

Comment: interesting! Only one thing. Why did you use Html.Hidden?

Comment: I included the RoleName property just for completeness but of course this could omitted if you had concerns regarding the value being tampered with.

Comment: I'm still getting null for the List<T>.

Comment: Sorry, error on my part. The naming convention for the key needs to match the class of object you are trying to bind too. I've now edited my code which I think should now reflect this but without knowing a bit more about you code I can't be sure. Alternatively, the solution shown by BeRecursive may work if you modify the lambda expression to m => m.Roles[i].

Comment: To make it work, I have to remove UserInformation prefixe => it worked. Then I tried the lambda version, as suggested by recursive, it worked as well.