# How to model bind to a List<ViewModel>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to accomplish something like this.  I feel like it's possible, and if not probably an oversight in the MVC framework?

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<MyViewModel>>" %>
...
<% foreach (MyViewModel vm in Model) {
    Html.RenderPartial("MyViewModelPartial", vm);
} %>
```

The partial view being an editable form, strongly typed to a single MyViewModel, and use the DataAnnotations on the MyViewModel class to validate

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FooController(List<MyViewModel> vml)
{ 
   ...
}
```

Is this possible?  This seems like the most logical way to build grid/table structures in MVC(with each partial view being a table row) but I can't seem to get it to work and I end up using FormCollection in my controller to loop through the whole dang form, and it's just messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Which is linked to from:

[Complex model binding to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231878/complex-model-binding-to-a-list)

[How ASP.NET MVC: How can I bind a property of type List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163783/how-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-bind-a-property-of-type-listt)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use that link to get the functionality I wanted.  The piece I was missing was the EditorFor Html helper.