# How to bind a List of ViewModel in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how to get POST values for MODELVIEW Pattern below. I can display the MenuItem as Checkboxes and Radio buttons,
but when user submits the form i.e. POST, ModelViewTest is null. I'm expecting List of MenuItems that user have selected.

```
public class ModelViewTest
{
    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> MenuItemList { get; set; } //Will be displayed as listboxes and checkboxes
    public Restaurant restaurant {get;set;}
}
```

ACTIONS:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
     //some code here
     }
     return View(new ModelViewTest());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ModelViewTest model)
{
    //I'm not getting List of MenuItems

    return View();
}
```

MenuItem Class:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string MenuItemCode{get;set;}
    public string MenuItemDescription{get;set;}
    public string UIType {get;set;} //This determines whether it's radio or checkbox
    public string UIGroupType {get;set;} //Determines the Group for radio/checkbox.
}

public class Restaurant
{
    public string restaurantName{get;set;}
    public MenuItem MenuItem{get;set;}
}
```

**Update**

Please see my View code snippet below:

```
<table>                                
    @foreach (var menu in Model.MenuList)
    {
        if (menu.UIType == "Radio")
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <input id="MenuCheckboxRadio" name="@Menus.UIGroup" value="@Menu.MenuItemCode"  type="radio" />
                    <label>@Menu.MenuItemDescription</label>
                </td>
            </tr>              
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <input id="MenuCheckbox" name="@Menus.UIGroup" value="@Menus.@MenuItem" type="checkbox" />
                    <label>@Menu.MenuItemDescription</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        i++;
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What is your view code - note also that your returned view in the post action will only have your submitted data if you include the model - ie return View(model);

Comment: plz also post the code for MenuItem and Resturant class

Comment: Hi Muhammad I've added MenuItem and restaurant classes. Please bear in mind I'm just making up these class. the actual classes much more complex. I'm trying to get the basic sorted out first.

Comment: What is the "ModelView" pattern? Do you mean the "ViewModel" pattern?

Comment: yes, ViewModel do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Please don't post additional answers as replies, simply edit your question or use the comment feature under the individual answers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the list of menu items in the POST action you need their corresponding values must be included in the html `<form>` and because this is a collection follow the [standard naming convention](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) so that the default model binder can parse them.

Comment: Had a look at the link and I still don't get how would dynamic group of radio and checkboxes be captured on POST. I've added the classes for MenuItem and Restaurant on original question

Answer (score 1):

First you should show us your view to know how you render your ViewModel.
However try this:

make partial view to be editor template for your `MenyItem`

```
<%@ Control Inherits="ViewUserControl<MenyItem>" %>

<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MenuItemCode) %>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MenuItemDescription) %>
.......
```

then in your view make for loop NOT foreach:

```
    <%@ Page Inherits="ViewPage<ModelViewTest>" %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

    <% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>

      <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.MenuItemList[i]) %>

    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

And please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163783/how-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-bind-a-property-of-type-listt/4163870#4163870)

Comment: It's not going to work with my scenario, if we add i for each checkboxes or radio buttons the group will not work. I need to group each check boxes and radio buttons based on "UIGroupType". e.g. GroupType could be dessert or lunch or dinner.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my View code snippet below:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var menu in Model.MenuList)
    {
        if (menu.UIType == "Radio")
        {
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="MenuCheckboxRadio" name="@Menus.UIGroup" value="@Menu.MenuItemCode"  type="radio" />
                <label>@Menu.MenuItemDescription</label>

            </td>
        </tr>              
        }
        else
        {
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <input id="MenuCheckbox" name="@Menus.UIGroup" value="@Menus.@MenuItem" type="checkbox" />
                <label>@Menu.MenuItemDescription</label>


            </td>
        </tr>

        }
        i++;
    }
</table>
```