# Binding a complex model to a list in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-3, view, binding

I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't been able to get the correct HTML rendered based on the answers given.

Related questions:

- [Complex model binding to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231878/complex-model-binding-to-a-list)
- [How ASP.NET MVC: How can I bind a property of type List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163783/how-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-bind-a-property-of-type-listt)

Here is how my code is setup:

**Model**

```
public class CustomerOrderItem {
    public List<CustomerOrderItemSerialNumber> CustomerOrderItemSerialNumbers { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShipperId { get; set; }
    public string OrderLineNumber { get; set; }
    public string LineNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return either an empty string (if no serial numbers already exist) or return the list of serial numbers separated by a line break for display in a textarea input.
    /// </summary>
    public string SerialNumber { get { return CustomerOrderItemSerialNumbers == null ? string.Empty : string.Join("\r\n", CustomerOrderItemSerialNumbers.Select(i => i.SerialNumber)); } }
}
```

**View**

```
<table id="orderItems" class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr class="gridHeader">
            <th class="lineNumber">Line #</th>
            <th class="quantity">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sku">SKU</th>
            <th class="description">Description</th>
            <th class="serialNumber">Serial Number(s)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i])
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Editor**

```
<tr class="gridrow">
    <td class="lineNumber">@Model.LineNumber</td>
    <td class="quantity">@Model.QuantityOrdered</td>
    <td class="sku">@Model.SKU</td>
    <td class="description">@Model.Description</td>
    <td class="serialNumber">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.SerialNumber)
    </td>
</tr>
```

This setup results in the following HTML (only the relevant part is posted):

```
<td class="serialNumber">
    <textarea cols="20" name="[0].SerialNumber" rows="2"></textarea>
</td>
```

The name always renders as [0].SerialNumber, but I need **orderItem**[0].SerialNumber.  I looked at Phil Haack's sample project and I don't see how he is getting the parameter name rendered.

Comment: How is the Model for your view defined?

Comment: @jrummell - I updated my question.  The SerialNumber property is a bit different since it's actually based on another property within the class.  It's basically acting as a friendly view property.

Comment: Can you show your Action method (at least the parameters)?

Comment: @jrummell - I'm not even trying to POST the data to my Action yet because I wanted to get the markup settled first.

Comment: @jrummell - I should also mention that this view is being rendered as a partial on the page.  So the list of `CustomerOrderItem`'s is being passed as a model to a partial view.

Comment: @jrummell - Thanks for your post.  I just figured out what my issue was.  I was passing my list of items to a partial view to make my original view look a bit more clean and concise.  If you pass your list as a model to a partial view and try to render it, MVC doesn't automatically add that parameter name as part of the input name.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I've worked around that before by making the partial a template instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing my list of items to a partial view to make my original view look a bit more clean and concise. If you pass your list as a model to a partial view and try to render it, MVC doesn't automatically add that parameter name as part of the input name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i], new ViewDataDictionary() { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo() { HtmlFieldPrefix = "orderItem" } })
```

Comment: That still results in the same HTML being rendered.

Comment: Really? I'm using that approach, and works fine. You replaced my code with your EditorFor line inside the for-loop in your view, right?

Comment: Yeah, I replaced that line.  It looks like that would require the editor template to be a bit different than what I have, right?  Your editor template probably looks for ViewData?

Comment: No, I use strongly typed model.

Comment: @MarinHN - Thanks for your post.  I just figured out what my issue was.  I was passing my list of items to a partial view to make my original view look a bit more clean and concise.  If you pass your list as a model to a partial view and try to render it, MVC doesn't automatically add that parameter name as part of the input name.

Comment: You are correct. The `EditorFor` call has to render an `EditorTemplate` from the root view for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `@Html.EditorFor()` and use `[DataType]` attribute in your model to mention that it should be rendered as a text area

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string SerialNumber{ get; set; }
```

and in your View

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SerialNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use array indices I don't think you need to have an editor template, but since you do have an editor template, use "foreach" instead. Just give it a try and tell me the result. As far as I know there are two approaches to the model list binding:

you go through a list like an array list[0] ect... but you dont use an editor template
or you go through a foreach(var item in items) EditorFor(item).. and use an editor template... but you have crossed the two methods that I know which perhaps is causing it to bug.

So try just doing a foreach instead, and check the result.